# Visual Studio Crashes opening Designer in Windows 8

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, windows-8

I move my code to a new Machine with Windows 8 and when I open a specific Form crashes, the only info that I got is the event viewer trace

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 10.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba1fab3
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.16496, time stamp: 0x52b3e015
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00012eec
Faulting process id: 0xfe4
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf291ffc379803
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 4c2c5c83-9513-11e3-be9e-6036ddc7195f
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Check your windows logs (in the Event Viewer) to see if there are other issues. Also try to run the application as Administrator to see if it's UAC related. It's sounds suspiciously like a bad install issue.

Comment: UAC is Disabled and there is no additional Issues

Comment: 10.0.30319.1 = VS 2010 RTM, install the Sp1 + all updates and check if this fixes it.

Comment: have yo installed the Sp1? Does it fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the .suo and .user files in the same folder as your .sln file ? Sometimes it get corrupted and crashes the IDE. Also please try devenv /safemode.

Comment: thank you  yes I have installed the SP1 but there is no fix

Answer (score 0):

My service was compiled by Visual Studio 12 on Windows Server 2012 R2. It produced the same "Exception code" and "Fault offset" as above. The error message recorded 2 times and stopped. My service has been running correctly.

I wonder my application conflicted with C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll. Windows loaded C:\WINDOWS\SysWow64\KERNELBASE.dll for my application. So it worked fine.